# Challenges working with typescript typed models when interacting with RESTful API

Tags: angular, typescript

To efficiently communicate with **RESTfull API**, I have defined a **model** class `Product` to experience benefits of `Typescript` over `Javascript`.

I am facing many challenges since get response and post request doesn't respect the same object structure. I need to make a better choice :

- **option 1**  : create two models (one for `post` and another for `get`).
- **option 2**  : create an adapter which transforms json get response to model structure class and adapt model objects to meet post request structure.
- **option 3**  : create a generic model class that uses `any` types and `nullable` fields to serve both `get` and `post` structures.
- **option 4**  : ignore using model class and manipulate javascript objects on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

What you get back from your `GET` is not your model anyway - just a plain JavaScript object that resembles it. I would declare interfaces instead and cast the received objects to that. You can also share whatever is common between `GET` and `POST` in one common interface and implement the changes in two more specialized ones.

Comment: is it worth adding all this logic for the simple reason to have ide auto-compete or to have compiler messages when I use int instead of string. I would go for the 4th option like the way we did with angular 1 it makes work easier and faster since I need to deliver as fast as possible

Comment: Right, except many people do feel that it's worth the trouble. And you say you have already built a model. I'm simply suggesting you make it interfaces instead of classes. Whether you want to centralize the shared features in a common interface is completely a matter of taste.

Comment: And a downvote because I recommended a tweak to a model you already claim to have... really?

Comment: downvotes doesn't have a specific meaning, in this context it means I am not convinced

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Comment: The downvote is silly here. The answer given is a sane answer that gives you additional information as to where your thinking should be heading to.The fact you're not convinced doesn't mean it's not a good answer and doesn't warrant a downvote.

Comment: @CobusKruger please edit the answer so that I can upvote it. stackoverflow: "you last voted on this answer 30 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."